# Using Specification and custom JPQL do not work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Passing Specification and Pageable to any JpaRepository method working fine. What I am doing is I want to use custom JPQL query method in repository, then I want to use Specification and Pageable instances in it. Pageable works fine, but Specification does not work. I have total 10 rooms, and only 5 of them have inventoryitem(it is another table which has manytoone with room). So my custom JPQL is working, it gives me 5 rooms instead of 10. My pagination is working as excpected. But Specification is not working. In query param if I pass project=2, it should give me zero room. If I pass query param search=deluxe, it should give me 1 room. But in both of these cases it gives me 5 rooms, which means that my Specification does not count. Is it possible to use Specification with custom JPQL query method? If yes what am I doing wrong? Any help of yours is appreciated. Let me show some snippets:

public interface RoomRepository extends JpaRepository<Room, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor

```
{
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT r.id, r.nameEn, r.project.id\r\n"
            + "FROM Room r\r\n"
            + "LEFT JOIN r.inventoryItems ii\r\n"
            + "WHERE ii.room.id IS NOT NULL\r\n"
            )
    Page<Room> findAllInventoryRooms(
            Specification<Room> specification,
            Pageable pageable
            );
}
```

Here is service(assume that all parameters come correct from controller):

```
public Page<Room> getInventoryRooms(
        int page, int pageSize, String sort, String order, 
        Long project, Long zone, Long level,
        String search
        ) {
    Map<String, Long> filterParams = new HashMap<>();
    if (project != null) {
        filterParams.put("project", project);
    }
    Sort.Direction direction = order.equalsIgnoreCase("asc") ? Sort.Direction.ASC : Sort.Direction.DESC;
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page-1,  pageSize, Sort.by(direction, sort));
    Specification<Room> specification = new InventoryFilterSpecification<>(filterParams);
    if (search != null && !search.isEmpty()) {
         Specification<Room> searchSpecification = new RoomSearchSpecification(search);
         specification = Specification.where(specification).and(searchSpecification);
    }
    Page<Room> rooms = roomRepository.findAllInventoryRooms(
            specification,
            pageable
            );
    return rooms;
}
```

Here are specifications:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class InventoryFilterSpecification<Room> implements Specification<Room> {
    
    private final Map<String, Long> filterParams;

    public InventoryFilterSpecification(Map<String, Long> filterParams) {
        this.filterParams = filterParams;
    }
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Room> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        // Loop through the filter parameters and build predicates dynamically
        for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : filterParams.entrySet()) {
            String fieldName = entry.getKey();
            Long fieldValue = entry.getValue();
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(fieldName), fieldValue));
        }
        return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class RoomSearchSpecification implements Specification<Room>  {
    private final String searchValue;
    public RoomSearchSpecification(String searchValue) {
        this.searchValue = searchValue;
    }
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Room> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.upper(root.get("nameEn")), "%" + searchValue.toUpperCase() + "%"));
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.upper(root.get("nameFr")), "%" + searchValue.toUpperCase() + "%"));
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.upper(root.get("nameTm")), "%" + searchValue.toUpperCase() + "%"));
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.upper(root.get("nameRu")), "%" + searchValue.toUpperCase() + "%"));
        return criteriaBuilder.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    }
}
```